# Improve performance of bufferedImage.drawImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I i'm trying to generate custom textures, at the moment i want to create a farmland

i created an spica-image and now want to paint it on my buffered-image

```
bufferedImage.drawImage(baseImage, (int) x, (int) y, paintWidth, paintHeight, null);
```

at the moment it takes for 49196 times 5632ms.

Is it possible to improve the speed since it paints always the same image?

Comment: How large is your image, and does `paintWidth` and `paintHeight` correspond to its real size?

Comment: drawing 50,000 times in 5600ms means an individual draw is ~110 micro seconds. That is really quite fast. Are you trying to draw 1 small image many times across a large image?

Comment: thanks, i tried to scale the image once before, and painted without w/h params, which gave ~30% performance

Answer (score 2):

***What I think you did:***

Let's first look at what you are doing something (as far as I understand) like below.

```
BufferedImage background = ...
int totalWidth = background.getWidth();
int totaleight = background.getHeight();

BufferedImage pattern = ....
int patternWidth = patternImage.getWidth();
int patternHeight = patternImage.getHeight();

Graphics2D g = background.createGraphics();
for (int y = ... ; y < totalHeight; y += patternHeight) {
    for (int x = ...; x < totalWidth; x += patternWidth) {
        g.drawImage(pattern, x, y,
                patternWidth, patternHeight, null);
    }
}
g.dispose();
```

Now you want to improve the speed.
The drawn image should need no scaling; width and height exact. What might be costly is the conversion of RGBA format of the pattern to RGBA format of the background Graphics2D.

If that does not help, one could use WritableRaster and [RasterOp](http://%20%20%20%20Graphics2D%20bufferedImage%20=%20pattern.createGraphics();).

***What java provides***

There is [TexturePaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html) for just this use-case. See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/TexturePaintDemo.htm).

I still have some doubts: size of the pattern image (one could make a 2x2 pattern), whether TexturePaint can be that more optimal. The pixel format can be very decisive.

Comment: thanks, but i think TexturePaint cannot help me, because i need to paint tem on random positions of the main image